# Creating either 2 dictionaries from CSV or creating dictionary from 3 rows

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have tried several ways to either create 2 dictionaries from one csv or create a dictionary with three rows for input and am at a lost, see the code below.

```
import csv
vlan = open('vlan_dev.csv', 'rU')
readvlan = csv.reader(vlan)
lookup = open('lookup_table_dev.csv', 'rU')
readlookup = csv.reader(lookup)
assignment = open('assignment_dev.csv', 'rU')
readassignment = csv.reader(assignment)
outfile = open('testout.csv', 'w')
writer  = csv.writer(outfile,)
used_header = False
for rows in readlookup:
    #creating dictionary for lookup table
    lookup_dict = {rows[0]:rows[4] for rows in readlookup}
    #print lookup_dict
    for rows in readassignment:
        #creating dictionary for building assignment to department
        assignment_dict = {rows[0]:rows[3]:rows[4] for rows in readassignment}
```

and

```
import csv
vlan = open('vlan_dev.csv', 'rU')
readvlan = csv.reader(vlan)
lookup = open('lookup_table_dev.csv', 'rU')
readlookup = csv.reader(lookup)
assignment = open('assignment_dev.csv', 'rU')
readassignment = csv.reader(assignment)
outfile = open('testout.csv', 'w')
writer  = csv.writer(outfile,)
used_header = False
for rows in readlookup:
    #creating dictionary for lookup table
    lookup_dict = {rows[0]:rows[4] for rows in readlookup}
    #print lookup_dict
    for rows in readassignment:
        #creating dictionary for building assignment to department
        assignment_dict = {rows[0]:rows[3] for rows in readassignment}
        #creating dictionary for floor assignment to department
        department_dict = {rows[1]:rows[4] for rows in readassignment}
```

is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I have also tried creating a separate function for the 3rd dict but it returns empty

Comment: Your question reads like, "I am trying to go to my local grocery store and grab four different kinds of fruit without visiting two different aisles. Here is the series of turns I have taken so far: left, right, right, left, right. Is there a better way?" How are we supposed to know? What's in those CSV files? What are you trying to get as output and why?

Comment: The First CSV(vlan) contains IP address assignments to a floor in a building, the second CSV(lookup_table) contains building name and building code, the third csv(assignment) contains building code, floor and occupant. I am trying to pull data into a dictionary to assign the occupant to a building and floor. The data I get from the first CSV imports into a final csv, I want to use the 2nd and 3rd to put that assignment to an occupant on the floor of the building

Comment: Try indexing each file first by bldg code, and creating a list of occupants, then loop thru the occupant list and get the pertinent info for each row.

Comment: Sounds to me like you're trying to use CSV files as database tables and Python as SQL. Dump those CSVs in a database if you want to explore the relationships and connections between them!

Comment: @Two-Bit Alchemist, I thought about that, but I have some experience with Python and none with SQL. The CSV files are managed by other groups and will be updated regularly. A python script will allow us to have an output that can be duplicated without database management

Comment: What OS and Python version are you using? There may be a way for you to easily transfer the CSV files into a local database, run one simple SQL statement which I can help you write, and even pull a new CSV out of the database if that's how your co-workers need the information. Bonus points: this whole process could itself be scripted in Python, you'd learn some new things, and if the solution ended up good enough you could probably beef up and share the database, which would prevent all this CSV processing by your co-workers.

Comment: Two-Bit Alchemist - I am on OSX 10.9 python 2.7. I have MacPorts installed with SQL and Sequel pro for the front end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following function to take 3 arguments to create a dictionary.

```
import csv
foo_in = open('bar.csv', 'rU')
readfoo = csv.reader(foo_in)

for row in readfoo:
    spam = row[0]
    eggs = row[1]
    foobar = row[2]
    new_data = dict()
    new_data.setdefault(spam, {})
    new_data[spam].setdefault(eggs, []).append(foobar)
    print new_data
```

this will give you a dictionary using 3 items.

Comment: When you post answers with code in them, it helps to [use the proper formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) so they show up with syntax highlighting and proper indentation.